# How to display key-value pairs from a JSON object using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I want to print **JSON** file in **HTML** page but I don't know the keys and the values my **JSON** Object.

When I know the form of **JSON** I use this code:

```
<div ng-repeat="f in faq">
  <div class="list-group-item clearfix">
    <h4>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">
        </span>
          {{f.key}}-{{f.value}}
            <span class="pull-right">
              <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
          </span>
    </button>
    </span>
  </h4>
  </div>
 </div>  
</div>
```

But in this moment I don't know the keys and the values of the **JSON**.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using some sort of framework to render the `{{ }}` templates?

Comment: @Soviut it should be AngularJS.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using angular(I noticed from ng-repeat). You can use (key,data) as follows:-

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, data) in faq">
  {{key}} - {{data}}
</div>
```

Comment: can u please accept the answer if u feel its correct?

Comment: Any clue how ti use in Angular2 with ngFor